# One percent discount doesn't work. How do I round this issue down?

Tags: java

Good day, I make a method with a discount on the number but the one percent discount does not work . Problem with rounding numbers ?

**Waiting:** price 65.

**Reality:** price 66.

**CODE:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int discount = 1;
        int price = 66;
        price -= (int) (discount * (price / 100));
        System.out.println(price);
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to round it down ?

**SOLUTION:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int discount = 1;
        int price = 66;


        double amountOfDiscount = (discount * (price / 100.0f));
        double priceWithDiscountDoubleType = (price - amountOfDiscount);
        int priceWithDiscount = (int) 
        Math.floor(priceWithDiscountDoubleType);

        System.out.println(priceWithDiscount);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're using `int` to store the prices etc. Try using floating point numbers like `float` or `double`

Comment: Float/double for currency is as bad as integer. After a few operations you would end up with some cents missing. One should use BigInteger/BigDecimal for that.